# Android device configuration problem

Tags: android, testing, device

I want to test my applications on LG P500 device. But emulator is not detecting the device. When i try to add USB driver which is there in SDK, it is not accepting . Please tel me how to configure Device for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled long and hard to get the correct USB driver installed for my P500.  I ended up installing a few different things, and over the course of two or three reboots I managed to get it going.

I'm pretty sure the actual setup details you need can be found [here](http://www.lg.com/nz/support/product/support-product-profile-mobile-redux.jsp?customerModelCode=LGP500&matchedModelCode=NOT_MATCHED&searchEngineModelCode=LGP500&initialTab=documents&targetPage=support-product-profile) (Note, this is the New Zealand section of the LG website - which is where I am, but it should work globally).

If you follow that, you should be able to install the USB driver.  Once done, go to SETTINGS-APPLICATIONS-DEVELOPMENT on the phone and turn on USB Debugging and Stay Awake - these help when you are using the phone to test code.

You can test that its actually working by going into the Android SDK folder shown below and typing ***adb devices*** (in the directory shown, remove the (x86) if you are using 32-bit windows) - mine shows up as follows:

```
c:\Program Files(x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb devices 
List of devices attached
80A354043044674101      device
```

I hope that helps - let me know if you are still having problems.

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks a lot for ur quick reply. In mean time , i installed the LG pc suite which contain USB drivers (Referring the manual ) . Now its working fine. I am able to install my test apps .

Comment: And can u tel LGUSBModemDriver_Eng_WHQL_Ver_4.9.4_All.exe what exactly this driver will do ? Even i installed this along wit PC Suite

Comment: pretty sure that the modem driver allows you to use your phone as a modem - if you don't have a data plan then using it would probably be quite expensive... but it could be handy if you need internet on a laptop while out and about, for example.  Glad its all working for you :)  Steve

Comment: Steve , Is there any way to access Internet in my Phone by accessing the Broadband connected to system using some app ?

Comment: You can connect using WIFI to a wireless router, but I haven't seen an app to do it via the USB cable - there probably is one out there tho.  I use my phones wireless at home, and at university, to browse the web, check emails etc.  Turn off WIFI and 3G (and Bluetooth and GPS for that matter) when you aren't using them tho, they suck the battery dry quite quickly (The first 4 of the 5 square buttons in the pulldown menu at the top of the screen - they are WIFI, Bluetooth, GPS and 3G, in that order).  Cheers, Steve

Comment: hmmmm :) thn probably we can write a app for that :P thanks for ur guidance Steve..

Comment: You're welcome.  This place survives on the sharing of knowledge - happy to do my small part :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your phone settings to allow USB Debugging. Home->Settings->Applications->Development->USB Debugging. Then connect your phone and run ddms to see if your phone shows up.The emulator will not show your phone, but it should be recognized in DDMS

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. I am able to run my application on my device.

Answer (score 0):

If some one trying to work on LG P500, Please follow the steps.
1> Connect your Phone to system.
2> Enable settings>SD Card & phone Storage > Mass storage only.
3> Now it will open the SD card. Go to PC suit dir, Install the application whc in turn contain USB drivers. After installation has completed desable mass storage only.
4>  Change your phone settings to allow USB Debugging. Home->Settings->Applications->Development->USB Debugging as Apesa ans Steve suggested

(Even i hve installed LGUSBModemDriver_Eng_WHQL_Ver_4.9.4_All.exe )Please let me knw wht exactly this driver will do . )